# Did the events of the Clone Wars have a noticeable effect on the relationship between Anakin and Tarkin?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader, the-clone-wars

I understand that much of the fifth season of The Clone Wars TV series went to further explore Anakin's motivations at the climax of RotS, however I am interested if those events particularly impacted on the relationship between Anakin and Tarkin during the Imperial Era.

The principal incident I am thinking of is Tarkin's involvement in

> the trial of Ahsoka Tano, Anakin's padawan, for the bomb in the Jedi Temple.

While Tarkin wasn't the prime target of Anakin's anger over this event, I can't help but feel that, given what happened later, it would still remain with him into the post RotS events where we see that he and Tarkin have to continue to work together, right up to ANH where they are together on the Death Star.

> Bear in mind that once he becomes a Sith Sidious would have encouraged Vader to hold onto his anger (as well as his hatred and fear) as this is likely to be central in ensuring the loyalty of his new apprentice.

Is there any documented evidence of Anakin expressing any lingering anger towards Tarkin over this?

Comment: My secondary spoiler tag may have been unnecessary. I didn't want to ruin RotS for anyone who might have not watched it yet. At least any more than Lucas did himself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Yes!

Or at least, Sidious thinks so. And the Emperor is wise.

First note that Vader certainly dislikes Tarkin

> Vader took a moment to reply. “The governor’s presence is unnecessary,
>   Master.”
>
> Sidious swung to his apprentice, his eyes narrowed in interest. “You
>   surprise me, Lord Vader. You have carried out previous missions with
>   Moff Tarkin. Has he done something to prompt your disfavor?”
>
> —*Tarkin*, p. 171

Sidious believes that this is because of the business with Tano:

> During the Clone Wars, Sidious had made every attempt to promote a
>   rapport between Skywalker and Tarkin, but the relationship had never
>   prospered to his satisfaction. Then came that business with
>   Skywalker’s Togruta apprentice, Ahsoka Tano, which, while it had
>   provoked further disaffection in Skywalker, had also created a rift
>   between him and Tarkin that perhaps had yet to mend.
>
> —*Tarkin*, p. 199

However, note that the preceding paragraph demonstrates that while Palpatine may wish Vader to retain his power by holding on to his anger, the benefits of Vader and Tarkin cooperating seem to supersede that.

This all comes from the novel *Tarkin*, [which is canon](https://www.facebook.com/starwarsbooks/photos/a.414408798712.177165.67519418712/10152378914593713/?type=1&theater).